# Error de Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto con Springboot y Angular.Donde el error surgio al hacer POST con MultipartFile. En el backend el POST me anda bien lo probe en Postman y me devuelve un 201 CREATED.
Pero cuanndo quiero hacer la solicitud desde Angular me devuelve el error :(Unsupported Media Type)

Y en la consola del backend me devuelve este WARN:

> WARN 3632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
> Content-Type
> 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarysNMyAIUjH3oMXyTq;charset=UTF-8'
> is not supported]

**Este es mi POST CONTROLLER:**

```
@PostMapping("/crearPaciente")
    public ResponseEntity<Paciente> crearPaciente(
            @RequestBody  Paciente pacienteRequest,
            @RequestPart ("file") MultipartFile file
    ) {

        try {
            Paciente paciente = service.crearPacienteConHistorial(pacienteRequest,file);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(paciente, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**Este es mi Postman:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi FRONTEND:**

**Servicio**

```
crearPaciente(paciente: Paciente, file: File): Observable<Paciente> {
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('pacienteRequest', JSON.stringify(paciente));
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    
    // Establecer los encabezados
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    

    // Realizar la solicitud POST
    return this.http.post<Paciente>(`${this.apiUrl}/crearPaciente`, formData, { headers });
  }
```

**TS:**

```
onFileSelected(event: any): void {
        this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0] as File;
    }

    crearPaciente(): void {
        // Usamos this.nuevoPacienteForm.value en lugar de this.nuevoPaciente
        console.log("paciente:",this.nuevoPaciente);
        console.log("Foto:",this.selectedImage);
        this.service.crearPaciente(this.nuevoPaciente, this.selectedImage).subscribe(response => {
            console.log("Guardado con éxito", response);
            this.mostrarNotificacion();
            this.volverPacientes();
        });
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container mt-4">
    <h2>Alta de Paciente</h2>
    <form (ngSubmit)= "crearPaciente()" #altaPacienteForm="ngForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.nombre"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.apellido" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fechaNacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.fechaNacimiento" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.telefono" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dni">DNI</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dni" name="dni" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.dni" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.direccion" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipoSangre">Tipo de Sangre</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="tipoSangre"  name = "tipoSangre" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.tipo_sangre">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          <option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoSangreOptions" [value]= "tipo">{{ tipo }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tiene_OS">¿Tiene Obra Social?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="tiene_OS" name="tiene_OS" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.tiene_OS">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" *ngIf= "nuevoPaciente.tiene_OS">
        <label for="obraSocial">Obra Social</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="obraSocial" name="obraSocial" [(ngModel)]= "nuevoPaciente.obraSocial" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="img">Seleccionar Imagen:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="img" name="img" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="image/*">
      </div>


      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Paciente</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```